# Unzip a zip file coming from server without locally saving in ios swift similar to what android does?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, zip, ios13

I have a specific requirement to unzip a zipped file coming from server.

The zipped file come through sockets in data format.

**Normal approach** would be to write that data to a file with extension **.zip** and unzip it using some third party libraries such as Zip, SSZipArchive etc ..

This works fine but the problem which I am facing is that, It should be unzipped without saving zip file locally.

The zip file contents set of images which has been zipped in by android system.

Is there a way unzip a zip file which is in data format directly without saving it locally, Or is there any workaround to achieve this.

Note:- I have seen Android has this feature, it unzips from data received and get the contents.

Comment: You can save it in cache directory or temp directory for a while and then delete it once your work s done.

Comment: @cerlin thanks this will work. but I wanted to know if there is any possible way where i an unzip  from the data object acquired from server, Like android does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the answer which I was hoping for. Finally found one in stackoverflow https://stackoverflow.com/a/30456344/1954633